# Keycloak with session cookie sometimes not working

Tags: php, angular, cookies, keycloak

Good Evening folks,

I have a weird issue about Keycloak and its Cookies. With Angular2, I send login data to some PHP API, and get back the access & refresh token. From that, I create cookies KC_IDENTITY, KC_SESSION and KC_RESTART sticked to  the realm-path.

In the Admin page of Keycloak I can see that I have stored the right Session-Cookie.

After I logged in to my page, I visit a site that uses also the same realm with a different client-id. It checks the login state via keycloak angular 1 example. Sometimes, I can reach the other site, sometimes, it overwrites the KC_RESTART and the SESSION is not valid anymore.

Because it is a really weird situation, I can not provide any information, because sometimes its working, sometimes not. Does anybody had the same problem?

Comment: i have same problem with keycloak 3.3

Comment: did you find a solution to this?